# Ruby on rails file download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, download

I created file upload using paperclip! File uploads as it is supposed to.
Than I added file download method like this:

```
def download
    sample = Sample.find(params[:id])


    send_file  upload.sample.path,
    :filename => upload.sample_file_name,
                :type => upload.sample_content_type,
    :disposition => 'attachment'
    flash[:notice] = "Your file has been downloaded"
  end
```

But I cant figure out, what should I put in my show action so that I would be able to download the file?

I got as far as this:

```
<td><%= @sample.upload_file_name =%></td>
    <%= link_to 'Download', :action => :download, :path =>@sample.upload.url, :type => @sample.upload_content_type %>
```

But it shows error : Couldn't find Sample with id=download

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't the link be to your action with an id parameter?

Comment: You mean something like this:   
<td><%= link_to 'Download', :action => 'download', :id => @sample.upload.path %></td> 
?
I a quite new with the rails btw

Comment: Url generated by your code will lead to show action...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you need to change your link_to to send the :id (that's what the controller action is looking for with params[:id])

```
<%= link_to 'Download', :action => :download, :id => @sample.id %>
```

Soz Karlis was writing as you posted :D

Answer (score 0):

=link_to 'download', @sample.upload.path
This is the easiest way))

Comment: mmm, easiest but does not allow access right control and requires path to be under public document root

Comment: i don't think that a person who doesn't know how to config routes and what is pathhelper know about IO blocking and how to config paperclip...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set download named route properly, you can just say

```
<%= link_to 'Download', download_sample_path(@sample) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have mismatch in your routes.

That is why, you have to:

1. Add additional **route** to your **routes.rb** for download action.
2. As it was said previously, you have to add link to your view (link_to).

Read this post for more advanced **Download** functionality:
http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads